# How to make a tiny control panel among splict view in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, nssplitview

Like Xcode, there is a small control panel to implement various functions:

[image]

Could I drag something to achieve this effect in interface builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Customisation of Xcode is not allowed at this time.

Hopefully it will be in the future.

Comment: Do you mean in my own peoject, I should draw a rect like this by myself?

Comment: I don't quite get it. DO you mean Xcode customization or you just want to replicate this bar in your own application?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my expression problem. I want to make a project with a control bar, which looks like the red-circled part of Xcode IDE itself. And this means replication.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Well there is no template of this. You would have to create this effect manually. Try looking at www.cocoacontrols.org and similar... maybe you'll find some library that has the same effect :)